# How can I launch graphical applications via SSH and display them on the Console?

Tags: rdp

From what I understand, if I issue this command in SSH, it should launch the application locally.

```
notepad.exe /session:console
```

As I'm logged in via RDP, I need the /session:console to display notepad on the session associated with the RDP connection.

, but nothing happens;)

The command just prompts.